# trigger not firing

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace trigger check_date
before insert 
on emp
for each row
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('test statement'||:new.hiredate||sysdate); --to test display
    if(:new.hiredate<sysdate) then
        dbms_output.put_line('invalid');
    end if;
end;
/


insert into emp(empno,deptno,hiredate) values(533,20,'23-3-12');
```

I have written the above trigger  but when i try to insert a new record into emp table,the record is inserted without firing the trigger.

Comment: Instead of dbms_output.put_line use a table, say mytab inside the trigger. Insert your test output string into this table mytab. After your insert into emp query mytab to check the test output.

Comment: @ArtBajji                                                                                             
Thanks it worked.But I want to display the String to the user using 'dbms_output.put_line'

Comment: You don't know that an end user will be able to see that though. It depends on the client, and then on settings. Why not raise an exception instead? (Also , `'23-3-12'` is a string, not a date; implicit conversion might get the value you want but isn't safe. Explicit conversion or a date literal is safer - e.g. `DATE '2012-03-23'`)

Comment: And, if you do just display that message, and even if the user does see it, *the insert still succeeds*. The user would have to see the message and choose to roll back; otherise you'd still get the invalid value in your table. Raising an exception [rolls back the insert statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-FA7A16B6-F94D-4E4C-A326-F602FE9FE3E8) to prevent that (but not the whole transaction).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code which has been attached above. The only issue I faced is the date parameter. Before passing the date as you wish, please check the default date format via **Tools->Preferences->Database->NLS->Date Format**. Then pass the date as provided in the default format. If not the date format needs to be implicitly converted using to_date.

It will be working fine as you expected.

Comment: If there was a problem with date format it would have shown error without inserting. But the record is inserted without displaying the message in trigger